# I have upgraded my system from 12.04 to 14.04 after restart when im tried to login authenication error came

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, authentication

I have upgraded my system from 12.04 to 14.04. After restart, when I tried to login, an authentication error came. After that, I used `sudo apt-get install -f` and rebooted the system. I didn't get any logon screen and system settings are not working.

I also tried `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, it shows some packages are broken. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Did you upgrade from 12LTS to 14LTS via **Update Manager**?

Comment: How did you upgrade: Update Manager, `do-relese-upgrade` or fresh install from DVD/USB? Also what was the exact error message from `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`